# How to declare an arguments of type void* in IDL

Tags: com, atl, void-pointers, idl

I am developing ATL project. Some interfaces contain arguments to pass the various pointers. Here is my IDL file:

```
import "oaidl.idl";
import "ocidl.idl";
[
    object,
    uuid(618E64F5-676B-4A13-A513-DE3D4097294A),
    dual,
    nonextensible,
    helpstring("IMyObject Interface"),
    pointer_default(unique)
]
interface IMyObject : IDispatch{
    [id(1), helpstring("method Make")] HRESULT Make(DWORD type, LPVOID settings);
    [id(2), helpstring("method Deserialize")] HRESULT Deserialize(LPVOID dataPtr, DWORD dataSize);
};
[
    uuid(E57065B4-498F-4347-9ACC-A2C86A771720),
    version(1.0),
    helpstring("TestComVoid 1.0 Type Library")
]
library TestComVoidLib
{
    importlib("stdole2.tlb");
    [
        uuid(1DC2528B-EA49-4F89-BB56-B1D667379644),
        helpstring("MyObject Class")
    ]
    coclass MyObject
    {
        [default] interface IMyObject;
    };
};
```

The first method of IMyObject constructs an object based on the type and the corresponding structure. The second method constructs an object based on binary data.

But I get error MIDL2139 : type of the parameter cannot derive from void or void *

In addition, I want to make a C# wrapper with IntPtr arguments to pass pointers. ("Add reference"->COM->"TestComVoid 1.0 Type Library")

I tried to use INT_PTR instead of LPVOID, then I get int instead of IntPtr.
I tried to use DWORD_PTR instead of LPVOID, then I get uint instead of IntPtr.
I tried to use VARIANT instead of LPVOID, then I get Object instead of IntPtr.

How to correctly pass pointers to these cases?

Comment: A void* is not Automation compatible.  You *have* to pass something type-safe.  Like a SAFEARRAY(BYTE).

Comment: Hans, thank you for the answer. But if used type SAFEARRAY, tlbimp generates type System.Array. I need IntPtr. What is "Automation compatible"?

Comment: Automation is a subset of COM, its core interface is IDispatch.  The one you are using.  It is the most compatible way to allow different languages and runtime environments to use each others code.  The price is that you have a restricted set of types to work with.  No void* or IntPtr.

Comment: I changed IDL file using IUnknown instead of IDispatch. It's the same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution. It need use a `local` attribute for those methods. Here it is:

```
[
    object,
    uuid(618E64F5-676B-4A13-A513-DE3D4097294A),
    dual,
    nonextensible,
    helpstring("IMyObject Interface"),
    pointer_default(unique)
]
interface IMyObject : IDispatch{
    [id(1), helpstring("method Make"), local] HRESULT Make(DWORD type, LPVOID settings);
    [id(2), helpstring("method Deserialize"), local] HRESULT Deserialize(LPVOID dataPtr, DWORD dataSize);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You got `int` instead of `IntPtr` because `INT_PTR` really defined as `"int"`. It means the `"int size pointer"` - not a pointer to int.

Just use `LPDWORD (LPINT)` instead of `INT_PTR`.